# 'Having' is possible in hibernate hsql?

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I want to use having keyword in my hibernate sql query as like:

```
 select from Store where storeName like 'a%' having productCount >1
```

Here Store is mapped with store table and storeName is mapped with store_name of store table and productCount is mapped with product_count of store table.

All the mapping is working fine. But when i run this query it is returning the following error:

```
 org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: having near line 1, column 43.
```

So anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You only can use `HAVING` together with `GROUP BY`. HAVING without GROUP BY does not make sense. In your example the GROUP BY clause is missing.

Perhaps you mean this (if you want to count rows)

```
from Store where storeName like 'a%' group by storeName having count(*) >1
```

or this (if there is a column with mapped member variable name productCount)

```
from Store where storeName like 'a%' and productCount >1
```

(P. S. in your example better use `from` instead of `select` - but that doesn't have anything to do with your error.)

Comment: It does not limit just to "group by" but to any aggregated function

Answer (score 0):

you can not have having and where both should be like either

```
 from Store where storeName like 'a%' and productCount >1
```

Comment: I tried with your answer but it again showing the error message:     org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:

Comment: The second example is not correct - having without group by is not possible and doesn't make sense)